# Activator.CreateInstance - parameterless constructor issue

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm trying to dynamically pull types from an assembly which have a base of EntityTypeConfiguration (Entity Framework-ism).  After I have all the types, I want to instantiate an object for each and pass it to a builder (DbModelBuilder) function.

Sample class:

```
public class LocationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Location>
{
    public LocationConfiguration()
    {
        // some basic stuff here
    }
}
```

I get the types no problem but I get the parameterless constructor error on this line:

```
var result = (dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

*P.S. I understand in this particular example I could just use AddFromAssembly() but ultimately I want to pick and choose which configurations are loaded.*

EDIT:

Adding a hard coded example of line that throws the error:

```
var result = (dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(LocationConfiguration));
```

EDIT #2:

```
System.MissingMethodException occurred
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at .OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) in C:\Development\Context.cs:line 25
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
```

Comment: Can you add the exception info?

Comment: I edited the question again.  See above.

Comment: "example", does that **specific** line throw that exception?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [mcve]? I find it hard to believe the code as posted would throw that exception so I'm assuming there is some more code behind the curtain here that we don't see. The class *does* have a parameterless public constructor. It *should* be constructible using `Activator`.

Comment: I did respond with more information to a potential answer but it has since been removed.  LocationConfiguration has a base class of EntityTypeConfiguration with a public parameterless ctor.  That class has a base class with a protected parameterless ctor.  I'm thinking the protected parameterless ctor is the issue?  Also, the two base classes are typed so not sure if that is playing into the problem at all.

Comment: Constructors of base classes are not an issue, it's the type you're trying to construct that is important. If that type has a public parameterless constructor everything is golden.

Comment: Have you checked that the stack trace's info matches your expectations?  I'm seeing that Activator.CreateInstance is being called on Context.cs line 25 - Are you sure that's the call you show in your example?  I don't actually see where you're calling it in your example code.

Answer (score 2):

If the below code is an accurate replication of your problem, then the answer is "because `EntityTypeConfiguration` creates an instance of `Location` within its own constructor."

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object thing = Activator.CreateInstance<PublicCtorClass>();
        }
    }

    class PublicCtorClass : ProtectedCtorGenericClass<PublicParameterisedCtorClass>
    {
        public PublicCtorClass() { }
    }

    class ProtectedCtorGenericClass<T>
    {
        protected ProtectedCtorGenericClass()
        {
            object thing = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        }
    }

    class PublicParameterisedCtorClass
    {
        public PublicParameterisedCtorClass(object arg) { }
    }
}
```

And in that case, the solution would be to create a child class of EntityTypeConfiguration and add a generic constraint to it which limits it to `new()`.  Like this:

```
class ActivatorSafeEntityTypeConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : new()
{

}
```

Hope this helps!